# Find the n-th derivative of the function $x^{n}e^{-x}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find the n-th derivative of the function $x^{n}e^{-x}$

I think general Leibniz rule is notuseful in this task because it is difficult to find elegant expression from $(f \cdot g)^{(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} f^{(k)} g^{(n-k)}$.
That's why for $f(x)=x^{n}e^{-x}$ I calculate $f',f'',f'''$ to notice some dependence and prove my suspicion on $ f ^ {(n)} $ inductively. However my actions were unsuccessful.
Have you some tips to this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $f(x)=x^n$, then $f^{(k)}(x)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\cdot x^{n-k}$ and choose $g(x)=\exp(-x)$, then $g^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^k\exp(-x)$. Then, the derivative of $fg$ immediately follows from Leibniz rule to be

$$(fg)^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}\frac{(-1)^{n-k} n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-k}\exp(-x)=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2k!(-x)^{n-k}\exp(-x).$$

Answer (score 0):

The Liebniz Rule is absolutely helpful here. We find that
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^ne^{-x})=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{d^kx^n}{dx^k}\frac{d^{n-k}e^{-x}}{dx^{n-k}}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(n-i)\right)x^{n-k}(-1)^{n-k}e^{-x}.$$

If we wanted to reduce the notation on the left we could write it as
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2k!(-x)^{n-k}e^{-x}.$$

Comment: But in your expression is $k$ and I think that I need expression in which not exist $k$

Comment: These are coefficients of linearly independent terms, you need to use $k.$